# Output specified value from function with array - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a function and get results through echo/return, by specified first value of array as below.

this is my code:

```
<?php
function getInfo($info) {
    $info = array(
        'some value',
        'some value 2' => 'some sub-value'
    );
    return $info;
}
?>
```

and display it in site:

```
<div class="input">
    <span><?php getInfo('some value'); ?></span>
</div>
```

but this does not work...
what can i do ?
thanks.

btw if can someone refer me to some really-good and advanced PHP guidance it will be really appreciated thanks.

Comment: @Anant i tried the echo instead of return. the function should get specified information from the array so if for example you write getInfo('some value 2') then it will output you what's after the "=>"

Comment: `return $info[$key];`...!? (Assuming you'd name one variable `$key` and the other `$info`, instead of overwriting `$info`.)

Comment: @deceze i will try thank you. tried but wrote "undefined" for info

Comment: So what exactly do you want to display?!

Comment: @callback if for example will be "=>" after the first one, or the second, that's what i want

Comment: So you mean the value of the key?

Comment: @BenThompson what is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on *"if for example will be "=>" after the first one, or the second, that's what i want"* i think you want to find out value from array based on the string passed to function, So do like below:-

```
<?php
function getInfo($string) {
   $info = array(
    'some value',
    'some value 2' => 'some sub-value'
   );
   return $info[$string];
}
?>

<div class="input">
    <span><?php echo getInfo('some value'); ?></span><!-- echo is missed-->
</div>
```

Note:- Make sure your each array index have some value otherwise nothing will print (in case here for `some value`).

Comment: yes! worked. thank you very much

Comment: @Ben [callback wrote the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36770551/476), and there it "didn't work for you". How is this different...?

Comment: @deceze Because no one use OP's original array and putted note what i added. Also no one said that `echo` is missed.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should look like this:

```
function getInfo($key) {
   $info = array(
    'some value' => 'foo',
    'some value 2' => 'some sub-value'
   );
   return $info[$key];
}
```

Comment: didn't worked for me. the point is to output it on demand i mean if i write getInfo('some value') then it will output the foo. my english is not really good to explain myself but it didn't worked anyway :\

Comment: ?! You write `getInfo` where?

Answer (score -1):

Use `in_array()`.

```
<?php
function getInfo($info) {
    $infoArray = array(
        'some value',
        'some value 2' => 'some sub-value'
    );

    if(array_key_exists($info,$infoArray) || in_array($info,$infoArray))
    {
      return $info;
    }
    else
    {
      return "not found";
    }
}

echo getInfo('some value');
?>
```

**In site code**

```
<div class="input">
    <span><?php echo getInfo('some value'); ?></span>
</div>
```

**Check live demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/557518)**

Comment: Working fine Live: https://eval.in/557468

Comment: sorry, I need to use array_key_exists(). Changed it. Thanks for pointing out. Please check edited code. @deceze

Comment: edited code. I have study your issue and i think this one work :). @BenThompson

Comment: i have written code if value not exist then it will give you key and if value exist then value will come as output

Comment: Try it with error reporting on... https://eval.in/557517

Comment: edited code please check. @deceze https://eval.in/557518